# У меня есть учётная запись с форума Русский язык. Как мне следует начать пользоваться Stack Exchange, чтобы не потерять вопросы, ответы и репутацию?

Tags: обсуждение

У меня есть учётная запись с форума Русский язык. Каким образом мне следует начать пользоваться Русский язык Stack Exchange так, чтобы не потерять все заданные вопросы, опубликованные ответы и репутацию?

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, следуйте следующим рекомендациям.

1. Перейдите на страницу восстановления доступа https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery.
2. Введите в форму адрес почты, который вы использовали на форуме Русский язык.
3. Нажмите “Отправить письмо для восстановления доступа” (рис. 1).
4. Следуйте рекомендациям указанным в письме (рис. 2).

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 1

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 2

Будьте внимательны. **Данные шаги должны быть первыми. Выполните их до того, как вы попробуете войти в систему**.

*Что делать, если я прочитал это сообщения после того, как попробовал войти на сайт, а как результат создал новый профиль пользователя?*

Самым эффективным способом является удаление недавно созданной учетной записи и **выполнения шагов описанных в предыдущей секции**. Если вы не хотите удалять новую учетную запись по каким-либо причинам, пожалуйста, пройдите процесс объединения профилей.

1. Перейдите на форму обратной связи https://rus.stackexchange.com/contact.
2. Выберете пункт "Мне необходимо объединить мои учётные записи".
3. Заполните и отправьте форму (рис. 3).

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Рис. 3

Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что вы указали ссылки на учётные записи с одного и того же домена. Объединить учётные записи с разных доменов невозможно!

*Как объединить учётную запись форума Русский язык с существующей учётной записью Stack Exchange?*

Первое, что следует сделать - это выполнить шаги описанные в первой секции - **восстановить доступ к профилю форума Русский язык с помощью формы восстановления доступа**. В этом случае, если вы использовали одинаковый регистрационные данные на обоих проектах, ваши учётные записи будут объединены автоматически.

Если после выполнения всех шагов из раздела восстановления доступа ваши учетные записи все еще разные, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом на почту nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Если учётная запись на `russ.hashcode.ru` была изначально привязана к StackExchange'евскому OpenID, то можно просто войти и без этой процедуры.