# Помогите восстановить пользователя-2

Tags: поддержка

Пишу здесь, поскольку другого места просто не знаю.

Ситуация следующая. 
Мне по e-mail'у написала многолетний пользователь с просьбой помочь восстановить аккаунт/доступ после самоудаления, о котором она теперь жалеет.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/997/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Что ей сделать, куда обратиться, чтобы мне не быть испорчченным телефоном?

Answer (score 1):

Для участников форума до его миграции на новую платформу (весной 2015-го) есть инструкция по восстановлению доступа: 
[У меня есть учётная запись с форума Русский язык. Как мне следует начать пользоваться Stack Exchange, чтобы не потерять вопросы, ответы и репутацию?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3)

В крайних случаях, если предыдущее не помогает, следует обратиться сюда: https://rus.stackexchange.com/contact (эта ссылка "связаться с нами" внизу страницы). Сообщения с русских сайтов попадут к [Николаю Чабановскому](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile), который может помочь разобраться с доступом.

Мне неясно, что в этом контексте значит самоудаление, поскольку аккаунт существует. (Если бы он был действительно удалён, то пути назад нет: пришлось бы начинать заново.) Если просто забыт пароль, то это поправить реально.

Comment: Мне тоже неясно, что это значит. ))) Именно поэтому я и дал ссылку на аккаунт. Спасибо огромное. Катя, вы читаете? Разберетесь, кому писать?

Comment: Как правильно написано в ответе, учетная запись не удалена. Когда-то давно, я написал публикацию о том, [как получить доступ к своей учетной записи](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3/). Если я правильно понял вопрос, то информация в статье должна помочь Екатерине. С нетерпением ждем её возвращения! !

Comment: Все уже. Спасибо. Разобрались. Проблема не в том была. Она завела новый аккаунт и не догадалась разлогиниться из него. ))) Конечно, удалиться она самостоятельно не могла при таком образе мыслей.